# Figure numbering IN figure

Tags: positioning, subfloats, subcaption

I'm using the `subfig` package which works like a charm. However, I only use the subfigure numbering (so no subcaptions, all the info will be in the main caption) but these are placed below the image which looks funny. I'd prefer to put the a., b., c. etc. stuff inside (or on top, if you please) my figure, for instance in the upper left corner like is possible for a legend. I'm not sure if it is relevant, but I'm using TikZ figures. Possibly the caption could also be defined in the .tikz code so I could use `axis cs:` for the placement of the number (a., b. etc).

Is this doable? I can't find anything related on the web or in the manuals.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=top}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\fbox{image}}\quad
\subfloat[]{\fbox{image}}
\caption{two images}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat{\fbox{\thesubfigure: image}}\quad
\subfloat{\fbox{\thesubfigure: image}}
\caption{two images}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It sort of does what I want, but not exactly. I know I'm picky. ;) I ended up using a text node in the tikz file as in `\node[draw=none,fill=none] at (0.35,3.7) {\small {\bf(a)}};` to achieve what I want. It looks nice and refs still work too. Not as convenient perhaps as automated captions but I can live with that.

Thanks for the help nonetheless! Cheers!

Comment: You didn't provide an example so there was no way to know what you exactly want (and to test solutions). But my second example should show you that you can access the current subfigure number from inside your picture.